# QueryHelpers.ParseQuery method doesn't get the value of one parameter from the URI

Tags: uri, blazor-webassembly

On my Balzor wasm .NET6 component I am trying to get the value of two parameters from the URI. One is called 'state', the second is 'code'.
I am using the `QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(_navigationManager.Uri).TryGetValue` method.
I can successfully get the 'code' value, but the 'state' returns null or the `if` statement returns false.

Am I missing something?

My code looks like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(_navigationManager.Uri)
            .TryGetValue("state", out var _state))  {
        string state = _state.First();
        //...
    }
    if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(_navigationManager.Uri)
            .TryGetValue("code", out var _code)) {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

The URI is:
https://localhost:44323/?state=2e693cb8-df60-4588-9d91-a8bb5ddc99ab&code=4%2F0AbUR2VPmBfVKafPjSu5LycAJQU64awZbx9jj0mKw7F7epByanv3I2mtLzkTiLk4_8HaBDw&scope=email+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=consent

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the method `QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(_navigationManager.Uri).TryGetValue("state", out var _state)`
doesn't work correctly when "`state`" is the first parameter of the URI.
This because the first parameter is preceded by the character `?` and not `&`.
A simple trick that worked for me was to replace the `?` with the `&` in the URI before parsing it: `string my_uri = _navigationManager.Uri.Replace("?", "&");`

I found out about this issue when I realized that `ParseQuery(_navigationManager.Uri)` was returning the entire block "`https://localhost:44323/?state`" as the dictionary key of the first parameter.